# Powershell: Out-GridView with List of User Profiles (Get-ChildItem -path \\$env:COMPUTERNAME\c$\users\)

Tags: powershell, profile, user-accounts, out-gridview

**Basic usage question:**

When I run

```
Get-ChildItem -path \\$env:COMPUTERNAME\c$\users\ | Out-GridView -Title "Select from User Accounts" -PassThru
```

all looks good, I get a nice pop-up dialog with user accounts to pick from, one account per row. Fields are Mode, LastWriteTime, Length, and Name (perfect, I'll pick out Name and LastWriteTime later, OK there.)

---

However, when I make it a variable in between, lisk this...

```
$useraccountsall = Get-ChildItem -path \\$env:COMPUTERNAME\c$\users\
$useraccounts = Out-GridView -InputObject $useraccountsall -PassThru -Title "Select from User Accounts"
```

I get one row with many unfamiliar columns, like:
Length, LongLength, Rank, SyncRoot, IsReadOnly, IsFixedSize, IsSynchronized, Count
SyncRoot seems to contain the list of usernames, and maybe more info.

**Q: How do I change the second code to show GridView output like the first?**

Comment: That's because InputObject in this case is meant to take input from the pipeline exclusively, similar to ConvertTo-Csv and Export-Csv

Comment: Duh! I see it now... this works!
$useraccounts = $useraccountsall | Out-GridView -PassThru -Title "Select from User Accounts"

So when would I use -InputObject ?

Comment: Normally, in most cases you do not, you let PowerShell bind it from pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Santiago Squarzon! Got it, skip -InputObject, just pipe it in.

```
$useraccounts = $useraccountsall | Out-GridView -PassThru -Title "Select from User Accounts"
```